# hgrc progress extension not loading

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

[The docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ProgressExtension) say all I need to do is add this:

```
[extensions]
progress = # shows progress bar for certain tasks
```

but when I try to clone this repo it doesn't let me because the extension can't be found.  It says it's packaged with 1.5 and later and I'm running 1.9.2:

```
> hg --version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.9.2)
(see https://www.mercurial-scm.org for more information)
```

Any ideas on why it's not loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from the "comment" you added on the line. According to the documentation :

> Lines **beginning** with # or ; are ignored and may be used to provide
>   comments.

You can't put a comment like this where you did. Just replace your config with :

```
[extensions]
# shows progress bar for certain tasks
progress=
```

And everything will be fine.

Secondly, as I understand you have activated the extension on the server side ? This extension must be activated on the **client side**.